# Convert pandas dataframe to vector

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to convert pandas dataframe to vectors? For example,

```
df
Out[53]: 
     Col1
3    Place
4    Country
```

Expected output

```
df_converted = 'Place','Country'
```

Comment: Expected output: `df_converted = 'Place','Country'` does't make sense in either Python or pandas. Do you mean a list `['Place','Country'`]`, a pandas array, a numpy array, numpy vector...? And what do you ultimately want to do with the list/vector, use it in a computation?

Comment: Also please tag and title pandas stuff [tag:pandas] not just [tag:python], that will help it get seen and get you get faster answers from pandas users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `values` on a series.
This returns a numpy array.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1': ['Place', 'Country'],
    'Col2': ['This', 'That'],
})

vector = df['Col1'].values

print(vector)
print(type(vector))
```

Output

```
['Place' 'Country']
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas dataframes are consisted of Series, the code that you shared above is about converting a Serie into a list. You can simply run following code ;

```
df_converted = list(df["Col1"])
```

If you want to convert a dataframe into another format such as a numpy array you can find more info at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html for the `to_numpy()` method.